# Entity Framework Select distinct multiple

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, distinct

Hola amigos quiero hacer un query en **EF** de un **DISCTINT** de multiples columas.
El query que quiero ejecutar es este:

> select distinct status, pregunta  from [MiTabla]

En entity encontré que puedo hacer un `select distinct` así:

`var result = EFContext.MiTabla.Select(m => m.status).Distinct();`

pero me gustario hacer algo donde me devuelva Status, pregunta, o cualquier otra columna de la fila que llamé, alguien sabe cómo puedo hacerlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te estaría faltando el método que ejecute la consulta y con `new` estas creando un nuevo objeto anónimo, podes crear las propiedades que quieras.

```
var collection = (from p in EFContext.MiTabla
                  select new { status = p.pregunta, pregunta = p.pregunta, propiedad3 = p.OtraPropiedad}).ToList().Distinct();
```

Comment: pero ahi solo estoy llamando a status y quiero llamar  mas campos de mi tabla